# How to evaluate double integral over function of square?

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't understand how to do this question. Can someone show work and explain please?

> $$\int\int_R\frac y{x+1}\ \mathrm dA,\quad R=[0,22]\times[0,10]$$

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the limits of integration
$$ \int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^{22} \frac{y}{1+x} dx\,dy
$$
Fubini's theorem allows you to do so.

Comment: Yeah, I realized...I was confused by the notation of the limits because originally my professor did notation like 22<=x<=0